# Best way to type "makeStyles"

Tags: typescript, material-ui

I know this API is deprecated/legacy, but I'm really curios about what's the best way to type this function/utility as to provide the type for props when using function value callbacks signature to define properties:

```
import { createTheme } from '@mui/material';
import { makeStyles } from '@mui/styles';

interface ThemeProps {
  alignItems: boolean;
  themeVersion: 'primary' | 'secondary'
}

const appTheme = createTheme();

const useStyles = makeStyles((theme: typeof appTheme) => {
  return {
    mainContainer: ({ alignItems }: ThemeProps) => ({
      alignItems: alignItems ? 'center' : '',
      height: '100%',
      padding: theme.spacing(2),
    }),
    subContainer: {
      display: 'flex',
      justifyContent: 'center',
      backgroundColor: ({ themeVersion }: ThemeProps) =>
        themeVersion === 'secondary'
          ? theme.palette.secondary.main
          : theme.palette.primary.main,
    },
  };
});
```

This works just fine, but I'd like to define the types at the very beginning in order to omit specifying the props' type every single time I use a function value:

```
const useStyles = makeStyles<typeof appTheme, ThemeProps>(theme => {
  return {
    mainContainer: ({ alignItems }) => ({
      alignItems: alignItems ? 'center' : '',
      height: '100%',
      padding: theme.spacing(2),
    }),
    subContainer: {
      display: 'flex',
      justifyContent: 'center',
      backgroundColor: ({ themeVersion }) =>
        themeVersion === 'secondary'
          ? theme.palette.secondary.main
          : theme.palette.primary.main,
    },
  };
});
```

the problem here is that the retuning type of *useStyles* is no longer what I need, instead of being `ClassNameMap<"mainContainer" | "subContainer">`, the value that it is "defaulted" to is `ClassNameMap<string>`.

Any idea on how to make it work without having to resort to something like

```
makeStyles<typeof appTheme, ThemeProps, 'mainContainer' | 'subContainer'>
```